# Defining a new style in xskak

Tags: xskak

I am experimenting with the various styles for displaying `\mainline` chess moves and observed that `\styleC` displays moves as a column of two half-moves per line. Ulrike Fischer informed me that the display width used in `\styleC` is `\linewidth` (which of course it would be unwise to tamper with) and suggested the alternative of creating my own style, call it `\styleD`. Locating `skak.sty` in my MiKTeX2.9 distribution I located one block with one reference and another block with 2 references to `\styleC`, pasted these blocks into the preamble section of my document and renamed the three occurences of `\styleC` to read `\styleD` (not bothering at this stage to change the definition itself). My MWE (or should I call it Minimal Not-Working Example?) thus created won't compile, with error `undefined control sequence \styleD`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
%following code pasted from xskak.sty with a view to redefining \styleC to my own \styleD (suggested by Ulrike Fischer 20 Feb 13):
\xskaknewstyleitem[%
 opencommands={\begin{tabbing}%
\hspace{.2\linewidth}\=\hspace{.2\linewidth}\=%
\hspace{.2\linewidth}\= \kill},
 closecommands={\end{tabbing}},
 blackopen=\>\ldots,
 beforenumber=\>,
 beforewhite=\>,
 beforeblack=\>,
 afterblack=\\]{styleD}
% 
\xskaknewstyle[level= 1,styleitem=styleD,font=\bfseries,
               level= 2,styleitem=styleB,
               level= 3,font=\itshape]{styleD}
%end of \typeD definition.
%
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\styleC
\textbf{styleC}\\
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d3}% 
\newchessgame
\styleD
\textbf{styleD}\\
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d3}% 
\end{document}
```

I am doing something wrong, but what is it?

Comment: Styles in xskak are set with keys: `\mainline[style=styleD]` or `\xskakset{style=styleC}`. The commands `\styleA` etc are from `skak.sty` (which is loaded by `xskak`). They are independent from the style-system of `xskak`.

Comment: @Ulrike ... so how do I invoke styleD in my document?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment: with `xskakset`.

Comment: @Ulrike ... got it. It works. But I may have to get back to you regarding setting the display width in my newly defined styleD !

Comment: Just a warning: I know that the style system is quite complicated (and if I ever get a better idea how to organize all this levels I will do it). Also it can need some testing to find out which of the keys to use to get specific effect.

Comment: ... everything in life is complicated and trial & error is the key to success. I don't mind that, as long as there are tangible results, and with LaTeX there always are. (1) I now have defined two new styles, one for single column and the other for two-column pages, as I don't know how to purge \linewidth from the definition of spacings, in other words how to define them in absolute terms. (2) Another thing I would like to do but don't know how to is have a colon character (":") inserted after the line number. A hint please.

Comment: 1. Simply replace the `0.2\linewidth` by e.g. 3cm. 2. If you mean the move number: `whiteopen`. Check section "An user interface for styles". There is an example which shows where all the commands are inserted.

Comment: Thanks for 1. and in 2. yes I am referring to the move number; I'll work my way through "a user interface for styles"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7632/discussion-between-reinhard-neuwirth-and-ulrike-fischer)

Comment: ... Stack Exchange suggested to move our discussion to the chat room. I tried but nothing appears to happening there as I am probably not observing the correct protocol: .. I looked at all your .pdf documents contained in my MiKTeX2.9 distribution and searched through all relevant .sty files, but nowhere could I find "a user interface for styles". Can you point me in the right direction please.

Comment: "Warum in die Ferne schweifen, wenn das Gute liegt so nah?". The section I mentioned is naturally in the documentation of `xskak`.

Comment: Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, I am sure. I searched for "a user interface for styles" and failed. Then narrowed my search to "user interface for styles" and found the section about two hours ago in xskak.doc, just as you say. You are good! Thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you write up your comments here as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Styles in `xskak` are set with keys: `\mainline[style=styleD]` or `\xskakset{style=styleC}`. The commands `\styleA` etc are from `skak.sty` (which is loaded by `xskak`). They are independent from the style-system of `xskak`.

The documentation of xskak contains a section "An user interface for styles" which describes how to adapt the styles of `xskak`.